# Why exception of "'outputChannel' or 'outputChannelName' is required" can be resovled by adding @SpringBootApplication when testing

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-test

I defined an inbound `IntegrationFlow` which will get messages from MQTT broker and route them to some channels, and the code is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MqttInboundProcess {

    private final MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter inboundAdapter;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mqttInbound() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(inboundAdapter)
            .transform(new PojoTransformer())
            .<Data, String>route(Data::getType,
                    m -> m.prefix("Channel.")
                    .resolutionRequired(false)
                    .defaultOutputChannel("TypeUnknown"))
            .get();
    }
}
```

I tried to define a new `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` instance  in testing such as:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class MqttInboundProcessTest {
    //Some tests here

    @Configuration
    public static class MqttContext {
        @Bean
        public MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter inbound() {
            DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory pahoClientFactory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
            MqttConnectOptions connectionOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
            connectionOptions.setServerURIs(new String[] { "tcp://localhost:1883" });
            pahoClientFactory.setConnectionOptions(connectionOptions);
            MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("testIn", pahoClientFactory, "testTopic");
            adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
            adapter.setQos(1);
            return adapter;
        }
    }
}
```

And then, it occurred an exception said `java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'outputChannel' or 'outputChannelName' is required`. However, if I changed the annotation from `@Configuration` to `@SpringBootApplication`, everything worked fine. I really don't know the differences between the two annotations in the case. Or, may I know are there any other necessary annotations besides `@Configuration` to make the test work please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s because a Spring Integration infrastructure is activated only when you have an `@EnableIntegration` which really comes together with Spring Boot auto-configuration. See more here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#configuration-enable-integration

Comment: It still occurs the same exception if I use `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@EnableIntegration` and `@Configuration` instead of `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Try `@ComponentScan` also. Your `MqttInboundProcess` is not visible without that and `@SpringBootApplication` comes with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bilan, it finally worked! But if the problem is `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` can not be injected into `MqttInboundProcess` due to missing `@ComponentScan`, the exception should something as `No qualifying bean of type ...MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter ...`. Why it always says `'outputChannel' or 'outputChannelName' is required`?

Comment: Huh? That `MqttInboundProcess` is not visible at all. Nothing just happens around that class. you have that `outputChannel` error, just because `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` comes without it. And since `MqttInboundProcess` is not visible, your `mqttInbound` flow is not going to inject this `outputChannel` there. A bit confusing, but you are just missing the fact that `MqttInboundProcess` is not processed without `@ComponentScan`.

Comment: Oh, yes! It's my fault that I really forgot the `MqttInboundProcess` is a configuration class...Thanks again.